# Optimising SQL query using group by and conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, database-optimization

I have two tables `fiches` and `fiches_actions`, the entries in the `fiches_actions` table are actions made on entries in `fiches` table, every action has an `action_id` representing the action.

Here is the schema of the two tables

[image: schema of the two tables]

### Problem

For every fiche, get the last action made on it (action_id), then get the count of every action made.

Another formulation: Get the count of every last action made on the fiches

I get the last action made on a fiche by getting the last id inserted in `fiches_actions` table for that fiche `max(fiches_actions.id)`

Those fiches have to verify some conditions

```
`fiches`.`created_at` >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
    AND `fiches`.`created_at` <= '2017-02-01 00:00:00'
    AND `fiches`.`status` = 0 
    AND `fiches`.`agent_id` = '51'
```

### My Solution

I did get a result by using this method :

First I created a view to get for every fiche the action made on it

```
 CREATE VIEW v_fiches_actions AS 
  SELECT max(fiches_actions.id) as id, 
    `fiches_actions.action_id`,
     fiches_actions.fiche_id 
 FROM fiches_actions group by fiche_id;
```

Then, I select the count from this view

```
select v_fiches_actions.action_id, count(*) from v_fiches_actions where fiche_id in 
( select `fiches`.`id` from fiches where
    `fiches`.`created_at` >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
    AND `fiches`.`created_at` <= '2017-02-01 00:00:00'
    AND `fiches`.`status` = 0 
    AND `fiches`.`agent_id` = '51'
) group by action_id;
```

And this is the result I get : which seems correct

```
    | action_id | count(*)
    | 3         | 6
    | 7         | 1
```

### My Questions

1- Is my method correct and I am getting the correct results

2- Is there a way to do this in a single query (without using the view)

Comment: The general idea for one query `..from v_fiches_actions fa  JOIN  fiches f  ON f.id=fa.fiche_id WHERE..`

Comment: I didn't make a join in my query, or i didn't understand your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is not incorrect, but it is more verbose and requires more work than necessary.

Here is another method:

```
select fa.action_id, count(*)
from fiches_actions fa join
     fiches f
     on fa.fiche_id = f.id
where f.created_at >= 2016-01-01' and
      f.created_at <= '2017-02-01' and
      f.status = 0 and
      f.agent_id = 51 and
      fa.created_at = (select max(fa2.created_at)
                       from fiches_actions fa2
                       where fa2.fiche_id = f.id
                      )
group by action_id;
```

For performance, indexes on `fiches(agent_id, status, created_at, id)` and `fiches_actions(fiche_id, created_at)`.

The correlated subquery (particularly with the right indexes) should be much faster than the aggregation.  Why?  The correlated subquery is only run on the rows that remain after the filter.  On the other hand, the aggregation has to aggregate *all* rows in the `fiche_actions` table.

Notes:

- You don't a need a view for the query.
- For date constants, you don't need the time.
- Table aliases make the query much easier to write and to read.
- Don't use single quotes for `51`, assuming that the id is a number.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct answer, i was mistaken in the results.  Thank you for your notes :)

Answer (score 1):

If id is the primary key which can be used to join the tables you could make it without using two selects.

You could make it without a second select:

`CREATE VIEW col1, col2, count(*) as new_col 
 AS SELECT FROM Table1 INNER JOIN OtherTable ON ID = ID 
 WHERE created_at.table1 BETWEEN 2016-01-01 AND 2017-02-01 AND status.table1 =o AND  agent_id.table1 = 51 AND..`

Comment: Thx Raphael for your answer, but there is no grouping by the `action_id` in your answer, and i didn't want to work with `views`